# Why does the first execution of a mysql query with no query cache takes longer time than later executions?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to optimize a query of the form `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE col FROM TABLE ..`. When I first connect to the database and execute the query it takes about 9 seconds. When I execute the query the second time it takes almost 0.1 seconds. I place the [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html) in the query to ensure that mysql is not reading the result from cache. My question is why does the first execution of the query, right after the connecting to the database (`mysql -uroot ...`  ) takes significantly longer than subsequent executions. What is the actual execution time of the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL can take a while to warm up its internal caches. Remember, `SQL_NO_CACHE` means avoid the query cache only. The index cache is the most important from a performance perspective. If the index has not been read, there's a significant penalty the first time it's used.

If you're using InnoDB, which you should be, ensure that your buffer pool is sufficiently large. Most servers should allocate at least several GB of memory.

Comment: So first execution time does not reflect its actual time?

Comment: Like anything, the first execution time is usually slower.